# How to get Travis-CI build_number within after_script command

Tags: build, github, continuous-integration, travis-ci

How can one get the *build_number* (and other build metadata) from within the `after_script` command in Travis-CI?

What have been tried already:

The [documentation on build configuration](http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/build-configuration/) says this, in the **IRC notification** section:

> You also have the possibility to customize the message that will be
>   sent to the channel(s) with a template:
>
> ```
> notifications:
>   irc:
>     channels:
>       - "irc.freenode.org#travis"
>       - "irc.freenode.org#some-other-channel"
>     template:
>       - "%{repository} (%{commit}) : %{message} %{foo} "
>       - "Build details: %{build_url}"
> ```
>
> You can interpolate the following variables:
>
> - *repository*: your GitHub repo URL.
> - *build_number*: build number.
> - *branch*: branch build name.
> - *commit*: shorten commit SHA
> - *author*: commit author name.
> - *message*: travis message to the build.
> - *compare_url*: commit change view URL.
> - *build_url*: URL of the build detail.

Trying to get this to work within an `after_script` command as below, did not work at all:

```
language: java
after_script:
  - git commit -a -m "Committed by Travis-CI build number: %{build_number}"
```

It behaved as if `.travis.yml` file was absent/invalid (even though it did pass the Travis-CI YAML validation [here](http://lint.travis-ci.org/)).

It seems as though this should be doable, but could not find any sample that does this.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The string replacements you can do for IRC output only work there unfortunately. They're only meant to be used for notifications in general, to customize the output, but are currently only available for IRC.

There's still a way to get the current build number, by accessing the TRAVIS_JOB_ID environment variable. If you change your script to the following line, things should work as expected:

```
after_success:
  - git commit -a -m "Committed by Travis-CI build number: $TRAVIS_JOB_ID"
```

Comment: Tried this and it does not work, unfortunately - https://travis-ci.org/#!/hackersInCTS/spinach-android/builds/2599261

Comment: Fixed it! It was the colon causing the issue. But sadly, it is not giving the right value we want. For whatever reason, it is (the actual build id + 1)

Comment: I do not want the bounty to go waste, so awarding it to this answer, even though this did not quite answer my question.

Comment: Maybe it's because in the `after_success` the environment variable is already set for the next build, if this is consistent you could just calculate the correct ID: `${TRAVIS_JOB_ID - 1}`. Or you could just query the [Travis API](http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/dev/api/) in the after_success.

Comment: @Odi: Thank you for your suggestion! AT the very long last, I got this one working: `$((TRAVIS_JOB_ID - 1))`

Answer (score 0):

I use this in my deploy script:

```
git commit -am "Auto deploy from Travis CI build $TRAVIS_BUILD_ID"
```

More on [Travis CI Documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Default-Environment-Variables).